# Ant variable does not exists in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ant, ubuntu, build, build-process, build-automation

I am trying to set up ANT build.
However when I invoke build command

> helloworld_15/${NAME} does not exist.
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Also the configure variables does not seems to be assigned.

However i have set them into `/etc/envitonment`
I tried echo `$<varaiable_name>` and value get displayed.

Tried to google but not solutions seems am the first one having this issue.

PS: OS Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 1):

The environment variables of the calling shell are not, by default, converted into Ant properties.  If you want to access them, you need to 'import' them using something like:

```
<property environment="e_pref" />
```

in your buildfile.  Once you've done that, you can access them by means of the prefix you just set:

```
<echo message="NAME=${e_pref.NAME}" />
```

You can set `environment=""` - i.e. an empty prefix - but you would still need the dot to access:

```
<echo message="NAME=${.NAME}" />
```

Comment: @Nishat - I've surmised this as being what you may need based on the build failed message, and the fact you mention `/etc/environment` - HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted out the issue.
Somehow netbeans ant does not access environment variables when run in sudo mode.
I didnt find out a solution for that but i settled down with non sudo UI fornetbeans.

Thanx for your valuable time and help.